# How could a 16-sector PROM Apple II access a 13-sector disk?

Tags: apple-ii, floppy-disk, apple-dos

When the Disk ][ first came out for the Apple II, the PROMs on the interface card only knew how to work with a 13-sector format. Around 1980, the Disk ][ was updated with 16-sector PROMs either for Apple Pascal or the newly released DOS 3.3.

This upgrade introduced a problem where now someone's 13-sector disks would no longer work by default. Apple addressed this problem by supplying two programs: DEMUFFIN (to convert disks/files) and BOOT13.

While I assume DEMUFFIN simply had the old 13-sector RWTS conversion code in it, but the BOOT13 was more interesting. Does it bypass the 16-sector PROMs? How exactly does it work and why does it work on the 16-sector PROM upgraded interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it bypass the 16-sector PROMs?

Like MUFFIN it got it's own RWTS.

> How exactly does it work and why does it work on the 16-sector PROM upgraded interface?

Because DOS 3.2 also got it's own RWTS code?

The PROM code is only used during the first two stages of boot, not during normal operation.

---

In detail DOS boot looks like this:

1. After Autostart/CTRL-P/PR#n the PROM code loads track 0/sector 0
2. Track 0/Sector 0 uses the PROM code to load sector 0 (again) thru 9 and jumps there.
3. This code already got it's own RWTS, independant of the PROM code.
4. From there on the whole DOS is loaded using the RWTS loaded in step 3

So BOOT13 just bypasses the first step, handles the second, using his own RWTS, then switching to the code loaded who continues with step 3

---

Sidenote: The reason why the boot code loads 10 sectors instead of like 13 is based on the state of Woz' development of the Disk II controler, at the time the DOS loader was programmed. Originally Woz used FM encoding and could store 9 256 byte sectors on one track. This was based on the data Shugart supplied with the drives. After some intense measuring he decided that these numbers where rather conservative and he tightened the timing to get 10 sectors per track. At that point Randy Wigginton started DOS development. The second stage should, for performance reason read a whole track and continue from there ons. So 10 sectors it was.

Soon after that decision was finalized Woz switched from FM to GCR to increase capacity by ~33% (10 to 13 sectors). But the boot sequence wasn't changed to reflect this.

Comment: I wonder if the ROM code could have switched off the drive automatically on boot failure (rather than spinning forever)  if it had used FM for the first ten sectors?  I examined the boot PROM back in the day and a pretty big chunk is used building the data translation table.  Using MFM would have eliminated the need for that.

Comment: It's a 256 Byte PROM. The code is already a marvel. There's no room for anything else. More boot logic would have resulted in the need of switching in a larger ROM. Beside more conflicts with other cards, this would have been more hardware. Very un-Woz. Using FM results in less data thn GCR. Same with MFM. Keep in mind, there is no controller, it's all software defined. FM and MFM can't be coded as dense as GCR, thus resulting in less density.

Comment: My point was that the code to boot an MFM sector should be smaller than the code to boot a GCR sector, so if the boot PROM had been designed for the latter that would have freed up a few bytes.

Comment: I don not realy see where the advantage is, beside reducing disk capacity?

Comment: The code required to read a GCR-coded sector is larger than the code needed to read an FM-formatted one.  If the boot PROM only had to read an FM-formatted sector, it could then have space for timeout/powerdown logic.  An FM-formatted boot track could then contain the code necessary to read everything else on the disk in GCR format.  If the boot track is only ever written as a unit, it could hold as much data in FM format as a normal track would hold in 13-sector GCR (since there would be no need for inter-sector gaps).

Comment: I still fail to see the gain. Now, they can be used as subroutine to read any sector on any track (or a whole series of sectors at once). The code is usefull in a bare machine without DOS. With your suggestion it would be confined to only read the boot track. Further, when booting an Apple one only closees the lid **after** spin up. That way the disk gets centered without effort. Also, no command entry needed to change the disk in case of failure. For stoping the boot process, there's the Reset key. So again, why is it good to remove usefull features?

Comment: The gain would be that having an Apple momentarily lose power when there's no disk in the drive wouldn't cause the floppy motor to run forever.  It wouldn't take much to add such functionality--I wrote a version of the boot PROM which could do that but it was limited to slot #6 since I took out the code that sets X to slot# times 16, but I think an FM boot loader could manage the auto-shutoff while remaining slot-independent.  In addition, having all disk types use an FM boot sector would mean new disk cards could boot old disks.

Comment: So you want to throw away all advantages for some esoteric use case? Thats where a custom ROM is more useful, isn't it? Also, the last argument would be as true with keeping 13 sector format - and as well destroy all usage of the PROM beside boot. Not a desirable situation cripling the usage of a device without any real gain.

Comment: Leaving a machine running while unattended isn't a particularly esoteric use case.  Maybe the drives were built well enough that having them run continuously for many hours on end wouldn't be a problem, but it still seems a bit icky.  Further, if boot code on the disk tries to use any subroutines stored in the boot PROM, it will likely be broken if that code changes in any fashion whatsoever.  I don't really see the ability to call subroutines from ROM as being an advantage.

Comment: You mean calling any ROM BIOS function is a bad idea? Don't tell this to generations of developers.If your application is to run unsupervised, put it in ROM. Or leave a disk in the bootdrive. After all, wouldn't you want to have such an application to restart ASAP? And BTW, I know many programms using the PROM RWTS to minimize code needed - very handy for games or other stuff that needs to boot from a single disk. I wouldn't want to miss the ability to use ROM functions on the Apple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65734/discussion-between-supercat-and-raffzahn).

Answer (score 2):

BOOT13 disks carry both DOS 3.2 and 3.3-compatible boot-sectors.  The DOS 3.2 boot sector boots directly if the hardware recognizes it.  The DOS 3.3 boot sector carries its own 5-and-3 decoder and loads the rest of the data manually.

It is possible to have two boot sectors because the sector prologues are different between DOS 3.2 and 3.3.